# Display a div if redirected to page

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to show a div ONLY if the page was reached via a redirected url. I prefer javascript, but php can work too. Whatever is easier.

I tried this PHP:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/site.com/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
echo '<div class="my_class">Hey</div>';
}
?>
```

The PHP above does not seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `&gt;div&lt;` and `&gt;/div&lt;`, but seriously,  you need to escape the dot `.` there  but thats not your issue `site\.com` the dot matches any single character in RegX

Comment: instead try `parse_url()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'site.com') !== false){
    echo '<div class="my_class">Hey</div>';

    }
}
```

try this one and replace site.com with domain you want to search for.

Comment: Does not work. I am wondering if it has to do with fact that the Redirect is happening at the registrar level and thus not capturing the http referer?

Comment: Print the $_SERVER variable at your site page and check if it has the desired value you need for HTTP_REFERER